# Delete List Items Using PowerShells with Date Filtering

Tags: list, powershell, splistitem

I've been trying to delete more than 10,000 list items in SharePoint using PowerShell. So far, this is what I've had

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c") 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

# "Enter the site URL here"
$SITEURL = "http://sharepoint/site"

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite ( $SITEURL )
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
"Web is : " + $web.Title

# Enter name of the List below
$oList = $web.Lists["Test List"];

"List is :" + $oList.Title + " with item count " + $oList.ItemCount

$collListItems = $oList.Items;
$count = $collListItems.Count - 1

for($intIndex = $count; $intIndex -gt -1; $intIndex--)
{
        "Deleting : " + $intIndex
        $collListItems.Delete($intIndex);
}
```

This deletes all items in the list, but I need to filter the items to be deleted based on date, like for instance (date today - 90 days) upon last modified date.

Comment: Is there a way to first get filtered records and then apply delete command only on those filtered records? I don't want to walk through entire list as my list contains around 1 million records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModifiedDate *should* be a regular old DateTime object, so you should be able to use this kind of thing:

```
$count = $collListItems.Count;
$date = get-date;
$ninetyDays = $date.AddDays(-90);

for($intIndex = 0; $intIndex -lt $count; $intIndex++)
{
    $listItem = $collListItems[$intIndex];
    if($listItem["ModifiedDate"] -lt $ninetyDays)
    {
        Write-Host "Deleting " $listItem.Name;
        $collListItems.Delete($intIndex);
    }
}

$collListItems.Update();
```

I would, of course, strongly recommend you test code snippet on one item first. You may need to cast $listItem["ModifiedDate"] as a DateTime object in order for this to work.